# Use Django model data in an equation

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-celery

So I've ran into an issue. I want to take the values from my model and use them in an equation, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'RankingHistory' and 'RankingHistory'
```

However, whenever if I run a print command for the individual variables it prints the corresponding number.

I've tried converting it to a list, as you can see below, to try and fix it but I'm still getting the same error. Feeling a bit lost after Googling for a few hours.

```
def ranking_updates(campaign_keywords):
    for keyword in campaign_keywords:
    rankings = RankingHistory.objects.filter(keyword_id=keyword.id).all()
    ranking_count = rankings.count() - 1

    # converted queryset to list to allow use with equations
    ranking_list = list(rankings)

    # variables used to find rankings location in list
    one_count = ranking_count - 1
    seven_count = ranking_count - 7
    thirty_count = ranking_count - 30
    num_rankings = ranking_list[ranking_count]

    # find 1 day, 7 day, and 30 day change of rankings + lifetime
    if rankings.count() > 29:

        # variables used to convert list from RankingHistory into variables
        first_ranking = ranking_list[0]
        one_day = ranking_list[one_count]
        seven_day = ranking_list[seven_count]
        thirty_day = ranking_list[thirty_count]

        # variables used to create changes over 1 day, 7 day, 30 day, and lifetime
        one_day_change = num_rankings - one_day
        seven_day_change = num_rankings - seven_day
        thirty_day_change = num_rankings - thirty_day
        life = num_rankings - first_ranking

        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(one_day=one_day_change)
        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(seven_day=seven_day_change)
        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(thirty_day=thirty_day_change)
        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(life=life)
        return

    # find 1 day and 7 day change of rankings + lifetime
    elif rankings.count() > 6:

        # variables used to convert list from RankingHistory into variables
        first_ranking = ranking_list[0]
        one_day = ranking_list[one_count]
        seven_day = ranking_list[seven_count]

        # variables used to create changes over 1 day, 7 day, and lifetime
        one_day_change = num_rankings - one_day
        seven_day_change = num_rankings - seven_day
        life = num_rankings - first_ranking

        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(one_day=one_day_change)
        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(seven_day=seven_day_change)
        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(life=life)
        return

    # find 1 day change of rankings + lifetime
    elif rankings.count() > 1:

        # variables used to convert list from RankingHistory into variables
        first_ranking = ranking_list[0]
        one_day = ranking_list[one_count]

        # variables used to create changes over 1 day and lifetime
        one_day_change = num_rankings - one_day
        life = num_rankings - first_ranking

        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(one_day=one_day_change)
        campaign_keywords.filter(id=keyword.id).update(life=life)
        return
    else:
        print(num_rankings)
        pass
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import SiteUser


class Campaign(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(SiteUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=70)
    url = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=70)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=70)
    initial_ranking = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, default='N/A')
    true_url = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=70, default='N/A')
    rankings = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, default='N/A')
    one_day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    seven_day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thirty_day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    life = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.keyword


class RankingHistory(models.Model):
    ranking = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.ranking
```

For reference 'campaign_keywords' is referring to the model 'keyword'. While the model RankingHistory is keeping track of the rankings of the model 'keyword'.

What the application does is scrape Google for any search term and determine the ranking of a website for said keyword. Then it stores it in the 'RankHistory' model for that specific keyword.

In the function my goal is to grab the ranking history of a keyword and calculate the movement over a 1 day period, a 7 day period, a 30 day period, and the life of the keyword (in terms of history in the database).

I'm trying to grab from the list of data in the 'RankHistory' model for each specific 'Keyword' to calculate this.

Comment: Can you give a bit of background on what you are trying to do here.. atleast a minimal set of exception backtrace will help understand where the problem is occurring..

From what i can see you are trying to do a subtraction operation between two Model objects.. i dont see why would you do that.. forget Django, even normal python objects wont support them, unless u have overloaded the operators.. What is ur model definition, and when you are doing a subtraction, between what two model properties are you trying to find the difference?

Comment: I made an edit to my question. Sorry for not being super clear. I'm looking to take the data from one specific model to make a calculation. Let me know if it's a bit more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: in that case shouldnt you be doing num_rankings.ranking - one_day.ranking.. ?, and so on..

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't know if that would work since those variables are not linked any models. However I did find a solution. I converted 'ranking_list[x]' to a string within the variable then converted it to an integer within the equation. Thanks for the help though!